Sphinx docs & ReStructured Text: Substitution on parameter definition on multiple lines
I am developing a project in Python that has hundreds of functions. A lot of them have a parameter called verbosity, which I describe the following way:
"""
verbosity: int, optional
    Sets how much feedback the code will provide in the console output:

    • *0: Silent mode.* The code won’t provide any feedback, apart from error messages.
    • *1: Normal mode* (default). The code will provide essential feedback such as progression markers and
      current steps.
    • *2: Chatty mode.* The code will provide all possible information on the events happening. Note that this
      may clutter the output and slow down the execution.
"""

As this parameter pops up here and there, I would like to replace a basic copy/paste by a substitution. I saw that this was possible by setting the rst_prolog parameter in the conf.py file, such as:
rst_prolog = """
.. |verbosity| replace:: description
"""

However, it seems that defining a substitution that way only allows for "description" to contain one paragraph only. Any idea how I could keep the text with bullet points I already have?
Thanks!

According to the docs for rst_prolog, and reStructuredText string is acceptable. Did you try indenting subsequent lines such that they are 4 spaces deeper than "description"?

No dice :( I tried and it keeps on giving me the same error message:
<rst_prolog>:5: ERROR: Unexpected indentation.
<rst_prolog>:6: WARNING: Block quote ends without a blank line; unexpected unindent.
<rst_prolog>:2: ERROR: Error in "replace" directive: may contain a single paragraph only.
<rst_prolog>:2: WARNING: Substitution definition "verbosity" empty or invalid.

Yes, substitution replacements only work for a single paragraph (which may, however, span several lines).
You may save longer or more complex source snippets to a file and insert them with the "include" directive.
